# Cannot read property '0' of undefined - ошибка при преобразовании к строке

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Нужно преобразовать к строке некое свойство обьекта, вот код:

```html
async function _createResponseArr() {
  try {
    var file = await getFileArr(user.fileUrl, user.insalesid);
    var newFileArr = [];

    for (var i = 0, len = file[0].data.length; i < len; i++) {
      if (file[0].data[i].length !== 0) {
        var fieldObj = {};
        
        // Не преобразовывает к строке "file[0].data[i][indexSku]"
        
        console.log(typeof(file[0].data[i][indexSku])) // тут везде number или string, пустые все отсеяны
        
        // Cобствено тут ошибка вылезает
        fieldObj.sku = String(file[0].data[i][indexSku]);
        if (indexPrice !== -1) fieldObj.price = file[0].data[i][indexPrice];
        if (indexQuantity !== -1) fieldObj.quantity = file[0].data[i][indexQuantity];

        newFileArr.push(fieldObj);
      }
    };

    return newFileArr;
  } catch(e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
}
```

Описание ошибки в комментах в коде. Не могу понять в чём проблема, пробовал разные методы ("" +; toString; String) - везде получается та же ошибка

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Также попробовал в 2м участке кода, где можно было нормально проверить на undefined - результат тот же

```html
(async () => {
  Promise.all([_createVariantsArr(), _createResponseArr()]).then((response) => {
    const storeVariants = response[0];
    const fileVariants = response[1];
    var variantsFound = [];
    var result = [];

    for (var i = 0, len = storeVariants.length; i < len; i++) {
      if (storeVariants[i].sku !== null) {
        var coincidence = fileVariants.find(variant => {

          // Вот тут проверяем на undefined
          if (variant.sku !== undefined){
            // Но результат тот же
            return '' + variant.sku === storeVariants[i].sku
          }
        });

        if (coincidence !== undefined) {
          coincidence.id = storeVariants[i].id;
          variantsFound.push(coincidence);
        };
      }
    };

    for (let i = 0, len = Math.ceil(variantsFound.length / 100); i < len; i++) {
      result[i] = variantsFound.slice((i * 100), (i * 100) + 100);
    };

    _updateGroupVariants(result, access, user.insalesid);
  })
})()
```

Comment: ошибка говорит о том, что либо `file`, либо `data`, либо `data[i]` - `undefined`. Нужно только проверить какой из них. Если только действительно ошибка в этой строке

Comment: @Grundy  Попробовал в другом участке кода, с проверкой на undefined - результат тот же, код прикрепил к вопросу

Comment: во втором примере непонятно какая именно ошибка. Непонятно что конкретно проверяешь. Если у тебя `variant` - undefined, то и `variant.sku` упадет с ошибкой. поэтому проверка неверна, а `storeVariants[i]` даже и не проверяется

Comment: а, ну и `null !== undefined`, Но `null == undefined`

Comment: storeVariants[i] не преобразовывается, да и это ответ другой апишки и всё что там может быть - null, на что я проверил,  дополнительно проверил variant http://prntscr.com/k2rw6v - результат тот же, к сожалению( http://prntscr.com/k2rx3o

Comment: без [mcve] который можно запустить и воспроизвести можно только пальцем в небо тыкать. Пока можно сказать, что ты должен проверять на `undefined` или `null` **каждый** сегмент выражения

Comment: На картинке с кодом у тебя 228 строка, а в ошибке - 110. Возможно ты просто смотришь не тот кусок кода.

Comment: @Grundy ... Да, блин, что-то я конкретно затупил( спасибо большое, проблема решена

Comment: как решил-то? :-) можешь написать свой ответ с пояснением что было не так и как именно решил

Comment: Всё банально просто, там отдельная функция логирует ответы сервера, а в некоторых случаях там приходит undefined. Из-за преобразования в строку, находились совпадения и отправлялись на сервер, от чего выскакивала ошибка, а я был уверен что это она появлялась из-за преобразования в строку, такие дела)